# How to iterate through a dictionary that has multiple values per key in Swift

Tags: swift, loops, dictionary, for-in-loop

My goal with this code is to iterate through a dictionary where the keys are a specific college and the values of those keys are the college colors. When a user chooses their college by typing it into a textfield, the background changes to their college colors. When I used just one color iterating through the dictionary worked flawlessly but now that I have introduced a secondary color my code keeps breaking with the error "For-in loop requires '[UIColor]' to conform to 'Sequence'", here is my code. I would appreciate any help

For my dictionary I used Color Literal to easily choose a color:

```
var collegeDict = ["UCLA": [#colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1)], "Stanford": [#colorLiteral(red: 0.3098039329, green: 0.01568627544, blue: 0.1294117719, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)]]
```

This is the iterator where the error appears:

```
    @IBAction func Button1Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        for (key, colors) in collegeDict {
            for (primaryColor, secondaryColor) in colors {
            if collegeName == textField1.text {
                self.View1.backgroundColor = primaryColor
                self.Button1.backgroundColor = primaryColor
```

Answer (score 1):

`for (primaryColor, secondaryColor) in colors` is actually the `(index, element)` syntax but then you have to add `.enumerated()`

```
for (primaryColor, secondaryColor) in colors.enumerated()
```

Nevertheless even with `enumerated()` the syntax makes no sense at all.

Wait, it does make (a sort of) sense this way

```
@IBAction func Button1Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    for (_, colors) in collegeDict {
        for (index, color) in colors.enumerated() {
        if collegeName == textField1.text {
            switch index {
                case 0: self.View1.backgroundColor = color
                case 1: self.Button1.backgroundColor = = color
                default: break
            }
```

---

This is the serious solution:

`colors` is an array and you can get the first and second element with index subscription

```
 @IBAction func Button1Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    for (_, colors) in collegeDict {
        if collegeName == textField1.text {
            self.View1.backgroundColor = colors[0]
            self.Button1.backgroundColor = colors[1]
```

Actually the comparison `if collegeName == textField1.text {` which is not related to the loop makes no sense, too.

Comment: @MarcE If it works for you please accept the answer. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)